# gunicorn active: failed, why don`t active gunicorn service?

Tags: django, gunicorn, ubuntu-server

i hav ubuntu server 20.04 and a django project
i set 
/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket

```
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

and 
/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and i have this error

```
 gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-03-16 11:49:31 +0330; 12min ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
    Process: 1891 ExecStart=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bi>   Main PID: 1891 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Mar 16 11:49:31 srv174847 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Mar 16 11:49:31 srv174847 systemd[1891]: gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process:: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Mar 16 11:49:31 srv174847 systemd[1891]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn: No such process
Mar 16 11:49:31 srv174847 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Mar 16 11:49:31 srv174847 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I entered the wrong username in the gunicorn .service file.
Another point is that the user we select for gunicorn .service must be a member of the www-data group, so we first check the members of this group with the following command:
‍‍‍‍```
grep ^www-data /etc/group

````
For example, we add user amir to the www-data group using the following command:
‍‍‍‍```
sudo adduser {USER-NAME-HERE} {GROUP-NAME-HERE}
sudo adduser amir www-data
````